# get current tab's logged in user detail in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can I get current tab's logged in user's detail in my chrome extension?

Currently, I get user detail of current browser's logged in user detail but I want details of all tab's logged in user detail in my chrome extension.

Comment: Depends on the site and which details you need so currently the question is unanswerable.

Comment: firstly I need user email address.

Comment: Well, generally you have *content scripts* that can access the web page, and you have *chrome.cookies* API in the background/popup which you can use to analyze the cookies. See the documentation.

Comment: Okay, Thank you.